# ConcurrentSkipListSet and re-sorting (java)

Tags: java, list, sorting, concurrency

I am using a ConcurrentSkipListSet, that is obviously accessed through multiple threads. Now, the values that are used by the compareTo-method of the underlying objects change overtime. Because of this, I want to 'update' the ordering of the list (by resorting it, or something similar).

However, java.util.Collections.sort(list) doesn't work, and just rebuilding the list is probably too slow (and would mess up the whole concurrency-proofness). Is there any other solution I should look at?

It does not have to lead to an optimal sort (which is near-impossible with concurrency and changing values anyway). Near optimal would suffice, as long as any remove/add-calls remain thread-proof (this would be a real issue when rebuilding the list when sorting).

Comment: Interesting question, but very difficult to infer any kind of story where this is normal!  What's the scenario, why is the comparison operator variable?  Knowing that, a completely different approach may suggest itself.

Comment: @Will It sounds like the elements are mutable.

Comment: An object is in a sorted position from it location in a data structure. To change its position you have to change the structure.

Comment: I would consider refactoring your collection so the objects do not change. Something this means using more than one collection so the elements in one can "move" relative to the elements in the other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every time you edit an item such that it's sort order may potentially change, you have to remove it from the list *then change the key* and then re-insert it.

---

Dr Cliff Click at Azul Systems has a [very nice presentation](http://www.azulsystems.com/events/javaone_2007/2007_LockFreeHash.pdf) of how they do lock-free hash-tables using tombstones and such.  If you go towards writing your own skip-list/tree to make the reordering of an item into a single - and hopefully faster - op, then you might also go this lock-free route too.  And be sure to share your results :)

Comment: +1: Have to make this very clear. You cannot change the value of any field using by compareTo(), or hashCode() and equals() for Hash collections, and expect it to work. For this reason its best to make such fields final.

Comment: A lot more pertinent question is - how do we maintain sort order when such a functionality is required from Hashed collections? That's what the original question intends to achieve.

Comment: @GauravSaxena we maintain it by removing, then modifying key, then re-inserting

Comment: @Will : At this moment, your answer is the closest to what I was looking for. It is roughly as far as I came myself, so I'm still hoping for a more satisfying solution. If none comes, yours will be accepted

Comment: Its an interesting aside that in my game engines and even for the timeouts in my hellepoll webserver I have used custom always-sorted containers that do support explicit moving of items - i.e. trying to efficiently do the remove, update and insert in a single step.  However, I'm skeptical that its really worth it and if you're in Java you'll end up having to make your own containers which is likely to be much buggier than faster.  I'm curious, are skip-lists really as great in practice as they sound?  How's it been and can you compare performance to classic trees?

Answer (score 2):

These types of collections in the Java API do not support mutable elements (i.e. elements where the compareTo method changes). As such, the only way to do it is re-assemble a new list in an atomic way, or as Will suggests you can perform a remove, mutate and re-insert of the element.

HashSet has the same problem - the hash bucket is calculated on insertion of an object, then you won't be able to do `set.contains( ... )` if you mutate the object's hash code.

To be exact, collections like ConcurrentSkipListSet and HashSet perform their comparisons/hashing on insertion and removal. The only collections that 'support' mutable elements do not perform special insertion logic based on the state of the elements (e.g. an ArrayList).

The [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) for the Set interface states:

> Note: Great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as set elements. The behavior of a set is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is an element in the set. A special case of this prohibition is that it is not permissible for a set to contain itself as an element.

and the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) for the SortedSet interface states:

> Note that the ordering maintained by a sorted set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if the sorted set is to correctly implement the Set interface. (See the Comparable interface or Comparator interface for a precise definition of consistent with equals.) This is so because the Set interface is defined in terms of the equals operation, but a sorted set performs all element comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method, so two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the sorted set, equal. The behavior of a sorted set is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Set interface.

Comment: Do you have a reference, where the guidelines may be given?

Comment: You say 'Most' of these types. Do you mean 'all'? If not: which types of collections /do/ support mutable elements?

Comment: @GauravSaxena I have added some Java API references - is this sufficient?

Comment: Thanks for clearing up your answer. However, although it /does/ provide a formal reasoning to why I want to ask this question, it doesn't provide a solution :(